# How does a home router acquire its IP address ?

Tags: networking, router, ip-address

When you first turn on your home router, how does it acquire a public IP address ? Is it a statically assigned IP address given to you by your ISP provider ? Or does the router act as a DHCP client in obtaining a dynamic address. If the router acts as a DHCP client, which server does it request to for an IP address ? And does it have to do a DHCP request every time you turn on the router ?

Comment: Good questions. But very broad and mostly unanswerable in more than general terms. Whether static or dynamic depends on the service you purchase. But mainly your router plays little role in how things operate as it’s the ISP’s modem that bridges your network to the ISP’s network. So the service provider and type of service play a huge role in how your router needs to be configured.

Comment: What is the purpose of your questions, be more specific?

Comment: @grawity Well, comment converted to answer.

Comment: @Appleoddity I am currently taking a computer networking class. I am just curious to find out how routers are assigned IP addresses because it was not covered much in class. We learnt DHCP protocol when devices try to obtain dynamic IP addresses but not the case for routers.

Answer (score 1):

> When you first turn on your home router, how does it acquire a public IP address ?

In most cases any new SOHO router is set to obtain external IP dynamically (DHCP). Any other setting needs some hand-set values for proper connection.

> which server does it request to for an IP address ?

Router sends its DHCP request like a broadcast. So the provider's DHCP accepts it (if it exists and if current client connection must use DHCP).

> does it have to do a DHCP request every time you turn on the router ?

Yes.

Moreover, when router's address is set from DHCP, it has a property of its max. possible age (leased time), and when this time expired (in real - when near 80% of leased time expires) the router sends DHCP request again to renew the lease and reset leased time (but DHCP server in some cases may not renew, but alter leased IP address).

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer ! it answered the questions that i had in my post !

Answer (score 1):

It actually depends a bit on your modem, but broadly that's how it works. There might be different protocols and setup until your modem, - with various protocols like PPPoe and such

[image]

here's an example of various ones my old router supports. (I have it disabled since I use it as an AP). Many of these run DHCP over the other protocol.

These *may* optionally use DHCP or static addressing for IPv4 depending on your ISP, and the lease times depend entirely on your ISP.

I run my own linux router, on a perfectly vanilla ONT  - and it uses the same basic settings as it would as it was a client - automatic DHCP.

Looking at DHCP client logs (not my actual IPs - swapped them out for RFC 5737 IPs, and swapped out some other things for bogus values)

```
Nov 13 09:20:44 heckate_router dhclient[1231]: Internet Systems Consortium DHCP Client 4.3.5
Nov 13 09:20:44 heckate_router dhclient[1231]: Copyright 2004-2016 Internet Systems Consortium.
Nov 13 09:20:44 heckate_router dhclient[1231]: All rights reserved.
Nov 13 09:20:44 heckate_router dhclient[1231]: For info, please visit https://www.isc.org/software/dhcp/
Nov 13 09:20:44 heckate_router dhclient[1231]:
Nov 13 09:20:44 heckate_router dhclient[1231]: Listening on LPF/enp1s0/FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF
Nov 13 09:20:44 heckate_router dhclient[1231]: Sending on   LPF/enp1s0/FF:FF:FF:FF:FF:FF
Nov 13 09:20:44 heckate_router dhclient[1231]: Sending on   Socket/fallback
Nov 13 09:20:44 heckate_router dhclient[1231]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp1s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 3 (xid=0xDEADBEEF)
Nov 13 09:20:47 heckate_router dhclient[1231]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp1s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 8 (xid=0xDEADBEEF)
Nov 13 09:20:55 heckate_router dhclient[1231]: DHCPDISCOVER on enp1s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 interval 17 (xid=0xDEADBEEF)
Nov 13 09:20:55 heckate_router dhclient[1231]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.0.2.197 on enp1s0 to 255.255.255.255 port 67 (xid=0xDEADBEEF)
Nov 13 09:20:55 heckate_router dhclient[1231]: DHCPOFFER of 192.0.2.197 from 203.0.113.3
Nov 13 09:20:55 heckate_router dhclient[1231]: DHCPACK of 192.0.2.197 from 203.0.113.3
Nov 13 09:20:55 heckate_router dhclient[1231]: bound to 192.0.2.197 -- renewal in 74135 seconds.
Nov 14 05:56:30 heckate_router dhclient[1794]: DHCPREQUEST of 192.0.2.197 on enp1s0 to 198.51.100.201 port 67 (xid=0xDEADBEEF)
Nov 14 05:56:30 heckate_router dhclient[1794]: DHCPACK of 192.0.2.197 from 172.17.0.201
Nov 14 05:56:30 heckate_router dhclient[1794]: bound to 192.0.2.197 -- renewal in 88638 seconds.
```

This is almost the same way it would work inside a lan, and the IP address lease is refreshed periodically. In fact, on the "internet" facing end, once the underlying protocol is negotiated (in my case by the ONT, or in other cases your modem), it is indistinguishable from a client machine in your lan

Comment: Hey appreciate your detailed answer ! it was helpful !

Answer (score 0):

In the context of the service you contracted from your ISP and their network :

- Your ISP issue router gets a static IP address

**or**

- Your ISP issue router gets a dynamic IP address

The specific protocol that handles the IP assignment can vary depending on how up-to-date your ISP is in terms of equipment.

Assuming your ISP is using DHCP to address your ISP issue router your router is indeed a client to it and it get's it's address from a server within your provider's network.
 When you first connect your router it does send a broadcast to the network requesting an address. When it get's one the type of address comes into play. If you have a static IP address this address will not change.

But more commonly a dynamic address is contracted and it has a lease time, that being how long it lasts until requiring renewal.
 If you shutdown your router, and turn it back it won't request a new address because it already has one, assuming the lease is still valid ( If the router has the address in memory or the server keeps track of who is what address is another issue). Usually when the lease is halfway through it's time, a new IP is requested.

Comment: Hey thanks for your answer it was helpful in helping me understand computer networking even more !

Comment: @calveeen I'm glad I was of use!

Comment: Just to check my understanding IANA is an organization that hands allocates IP addresses to countries around the world. Within those countries, IP addresses are allocated to the different service providers in the country. Based on the IP addresses allocated to each ISP, the router may use DHCP to obtain one of the free IP addresses given to the ISP ?

Comment: @calveen It's a little more complicated than that. I can't quite recall which organization handles addressing on that level but I have a feeling it is indeed IANA. The bulk of problem is the addressing space in IPv4, which simply isn't enough for every network and host. What happens is clever partition of the networks. You have global systems separated by regions and inside the regions you have ISP's which have their own networks. Your router gets an IP from your ISP network, which in turn, their network has a router that receives an IP based on the region..

Comment: @calveeen Character limits are a pain.I took a remote course on this very subject that glazed on these networks and organizations and oooh boy lotta readin'!

Comment: Home devices get assigned private IP addresses right ? so the IP address that routers acquire from DHCP is the IP address to that the rest of the world sees. NAT is done everytime we want to send a packet out. In this sense, IP addresses would not necessarily run out ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/85739/discussion-between-ricardo-s-and-calveeen).